# Stripe - Change CurrentPeriodEnd forcefully

Tags: asp.net-mvc, stripe-payments

I'm working on a subscription downgrade requirement where the downgrade should be happen on next billing date. I've developed this with following steps

- For a particular subscription, get the next billing date from Stripe
- Save the next billing date and new payment plan in database
- Created an Azure function to run on every day at a specific time, which triggers an action method in my ASP.Net Core MVC application. This method checks for the subscriptions which has next billing date is that day.
- For each of above subscription, downgrade it to the new payment plan saved in the database.

I've tested this and working fine. But the QA team needs to forcefully update the next billing date to a date in near future (they cannot wait until the next billing date. They have to complete testing this story immediately).

Is there a way to update the **CurrentPeriodEnd** date from the stripe dashboard or through the API?

Answer (score 2):

You can't explicitly control `current_period_end` for a given Subscription but what you can do is change the billing cycle to match your needs. For example call the Update Subscription [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update) and pass `trial_end` set to a timestamp of when you want `current_period_end` to be.

You can also create a new subscription and pass he `billing_cycle_anchor` parameter to anchor the subscription to that specific date as documented [here](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/billing-cycle#new-subscriptions).